# TinyMCE 404/undefined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, path, tinymce, relative-path

I am using TinyMCE with Twitter Bootstrap v3.1 in a Q/A application.

For some reason I am getting multiple 404 errors from TinyMCE in console:

```
GET http://localhost/assets/lib/TinyMCE/themes/modern/themeundefined.js 404 (Not Found) tinymce.min.js:3
Failed to load: /assets/lib/TinyMCE//themes/modern/themeundefined.js
```

As far as I can see the path is correct. I have typed the path directly into the browser bar (without undefinedtheme.js) and it pops up.

Full path to TinyMCE is: `http://localhost/application/assets/lib/TinyMCE/`

1. I have mod-rewrite enabled, I have tried disabling but didn't help.
2. I have tried setting:

   - `tinyMCE.baseURL = "/assets/lib/TinyMCE";`
   - `tinyMCE.baseURL = "/application/assets/lib/TinyMCE";`
   - `tinyMCE.baseURL = "localhost/application/assets/lib/TinyMCE";`

I have searched the TinyMCE FAQ for the issue which pointed me to mod_rewrite.

Basically what has caused the `undefinedtheme.js` thing?

**My TinyMCE Initiator:**

```
//TinyMCE Initiator

//set scope
$(document).ready(function() {

    tinyMCE.baseURL = "/assets/lib/TinyMCE";

    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#tinymce",
        theme: "modern",
        /*width: 400,*/
        height: 300,
        plugins: [
             "advlist autolink link lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
             "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime nonbreaking",
             "save contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
       ],
       content_css: "../assets/css/bootstrap.css",
       toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify bullist numlist forecolor | outdent indent | l      ink | ", 
       style_formats: [
            {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
            {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
            {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
            {title: 'Table styles'},
            {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ]
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Just over a year later and a google search brought me straight back to this page and instant fix, this is exactly why people should answer there own questions, you never know who might need it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TinyMCE should be included before the textarea tag, not after**

```
<doctype html>
    <head>
        <script src="/assets/lib/TinyMCE/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container" role="main">
            <textarea id="tinymce"></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#tinymce",
        theme: "modern",
        //width: 400,
        height: 300,
        plugins: [
             "advlist autolink link lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
             "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime nonbreaking",
             "save contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
       ],
       content_css: "../assets/css/bootstrap.css",
       toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify bullist numlist forecolor | outdent indent | l      ink | ", 
       style_formats: [
            {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
            {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
            {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
            {title: 'Table styles'},
            {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ]
    });
});

</script>

</html>
```