# Not found themes and plugins tinymce laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce, http-status-code-404

i am trying to setup tinymce in my web application made in laravel 5.4. I dont know what happened but i made a few modifications and now it can't find "theme.js" and "plugins.js". I had this code at the end of my html file

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/plugins/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/components/post/create.js') }}"></script>
```

This is the code to initialize tinymce:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#tinymce',
    height: 400,
    plugins: 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview',
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.getElement().removeAttribute('required');
    }
});
```

I have all the files needed to run tinymce:
[Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTmKV.png)

Comment: You say it can't find "themes.js" and "plugins.js" and then show code trying to load "tinymce.min.js" and "create.js".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If TinyMCE is not properly calculating its "base URL" for loading other parts of the editor you can explicitly tell it where to look by setting `tinymce.baseURL` and ``tinymce.baseURI` to the path where the browser can find TinyMCE at runtime.  For example:

```
tinymce.baseURL = "http://localhost/myapp/tinymce";
tinymce.baseURI = new tinymce.util.URI(tinymce.baseURL);
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#editor",
    ....
});
```

Comment: Thanks, though i had another problem like this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705885/tinymce-404-undefined)

Comment: Thanks, though i had another problem like this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705885/tinymce-404-undefined)